# Copy line from text file and create new file for each line in php

Tags: php

I have a text file with 1000 lines or more, here is a sample content:

```
123456
123457
123458
123459
123450
```

I'd like to **open this file in php and create a separate new file for each line**, like 123456.txt 123457.txt 123458.txt.

Please help me, I am very new in php.

Thank you
Rezan Khan

Answer (score 0):

**This works:**

```
<?php

foreach (explode("\n", file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/my_file.txt')) as $line)
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.trim($line).'.txt', '');
```

Comment: Hi Thank you, let me try this